# Bitmap not included in System.Drawing (Console Application)

Tags: c#, bitmap, console

I'm making an application for the console, which handles Bitmap images.
The problem I have is that `System.Drawing` seemingly does not include `Bitmap`. I already tried importing `System.Drawing.Imaging` but as I read, it is not available for `.Net Core` (not sure though...).

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Comment: If you target .Net Core do TAG it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `System.Drawing` objects in a `Console Application` you need to add the `System.Drawing` also to the references.

1. Go to the right menu of `References`
2. Choice `Add Reference...`
3. Select `Assemblies`
4. Check the `System.Drawing`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I realised my problem was that I used a type of console app, which doesn't support drawing...